# How to add custom attributes to sign up form with amplify ui react libraries?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, user-interface, aws-amplify

I have a few custom attributes already configured in a user pool and I'd like to be able to add them to the sign up form using amplify ui-react libraries. For example, I have a custom attribute for the user's organization that I want required in the sign up form. I am more or less new to web development and AWS so please go easy on me lol.

The first thing I tried was following this guide [here](https://docs.amplify.aws/ui/auth/authenticator/q/framework/react-native/#customize-your-own-components) which didn't work. But reading the guide [here](https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/react/connected-components/authenticator/customization) I quickly realized that this was probably legacy documentation considering that the way the signup form is customized is totally different. The documentation here shows how to easily add and customize all the possible required attributes, but doesn't really show how to do so for custom attributes. The only thing I found was that you could just straight up override the entire sign up form and instantiate a new field with the basic field types provided making sure that the 'name' property of the field corresponds to the custom attribute as they show in [this block of code](https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/react/connected-components/authenticator/customization#sign-up-fields). I could do this, but the downside is that it looks like a lot of flexibility is lost in this approach. For example, I'm not sure how I can make fields required or set their display order in the form. If there is a way to reference custom attributes in the form fields object like they do with required attributes in [this section](https://stackoverflow.com), that would be incredibly helpful.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you can use the name of custom attributes as keys in the object passed into the `formFields` prop, you just have to surround the keys with ''.

So in my use case, this simply worked:

```
const signUpFields = {
  signUp: {
    'custom:organization': {
      placeHolder: 'Enter your First Name here'
      isRequired: true,
      label: 'First Name',
      order: 1
     },
     // etc
  }
};

return (
  <Authenticator formField={signUpFields}>
    // jsx stuff here
  </Authenticator>
);
```